# Dodge Caravan headlights; 1 on with running lights, other on with headlights

Tags: electrical, dodge, headlight, caravan

I have a 2002 Dodge Caravan. When the running lights are on, one of the headlights is on.  When I turn the headlights on, they switch; the one that was on with the running lights turns off, and the one that was off with the running lights turns on.

Any ideas? I googled this and on another forum ([here](http://www.automotiveforums.com/t356943-help__weird_headlight_problem_01_caravan_.html)) one reply said it was simply a wire that needed to be cleaned or replaced. I'm just looking for a confirmation or 2nd opinion.

Other replies there say the contacts on the Front Control Module (FCM) need to be cleaned.

Answer (score 2):

My Ride:
Dodge 2002 Grand Caravan Sport

I just fixed this problem on my car.

1. Take off the FCM (Front Control Module)  This is the metal box directly in front of the fuse center, next to the battery.  You'll have to take off the cover of the fuse box.  The FCM is held in by four torx screws.
   [image: FCM]
2. Clean the flat metal terminals by sanding them. 
   [image: Flat Metal Terminals]
3. Give them each a slight twist, to force a better connection.
   [image: Give each metal terminal a slight twist]
4. Put the FCM back in.  You're done!

Estimated time: 15 minutes (plus another 10 to find the torx bit you lost under the hood)

<sub>Update four years later:  still working!  The car has other problems now, but the headlights are strong as ever.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Did this and it still didn't work. BUT then I tried rotating the IPM and cleaning all the contacts on C1 (green) and C6 ("yellow") connectors seemed to do the trick.  Not sure which one did it, but they're now both on!
Thanks!