# Ford Edge 2013 Right headlight not working - fuse okay

Tags: ford, headlight, fuse, relay

2013 Ford Edge SEL in Canada (DRL is the highbeam at lower voltage)

Right side light started, weeks ago, with flickering while the car was turning to start, but stops flickering and works fine afterwards.

Now the right side low/high beam (one light bulb for both) no longer turns on.

Swapped lights between left/right, the right still wont come on. 
Checked fuses for Right/Left headlights, both are okay and swapped to be safe. Still no luck.

Using multimeter, checked the connector inside the housing, no power.
Checked the connector that plugs into the entire light housing, no power on 3 out of 5 pins (1 is ground, and 1 is for the 'parking' lights which has power, the rest don't).

Any thoughts on what could be the issue?
If relay, would both sides stop working? or could it be a bad relay where one side isn't working?
Hoping this is not a wiring issue so I don't have to start ripping out wiring from the car to replace.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the bulb?  Although if you're getting no power to the lightbulb, then the bulb itself probably won't change much...

Comment: Maybe related: a problem I had with my '02 Dodge Grand Caravan.  https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/21111/dodge-caravan-headlights-1-on-with-running-lights-other-on-with-headlights/21942#21942

Comment: I have swapped bulbs and tried new bulbs. Also the bulb that doesnt work in right side works in left. Vice versa as well, works in left doesnt work in right. I have verified via multimeter that there is 0 volts getting to the connector but ground seems fine.

Comment: Sounds good - just checking!  (And welcome to the site, by the way!)

Comment: Update: I've traced the wiring for the headlight all the way to the fuse box / battery junction, right before it goes into the driver side fuse box. I've tested the wire at multiple points along the way and I can't seem to get a connector disconnected around the fusebox/battery junction to test there, but even at that point there is no power to the single low beam headlight.

Comment: I did just validate, though, that when I flick high beams, I get power on another pin and I hear the click where the mirror flaps up or down. It's just the single low beam 12v wire that is not receiving power, and it seems to start around one of the 2 fuse boxes, or battery junction area but i can't find the exact wire in the battery junction, so assuming there is a missed fuse or relay that is causing this to happen and not in fact a wiring issue. 

Anyone think otherwise?

Comment: That sounds right to me.  Not an expert with newer Fords, or wiring in general, but do read through that link I posted above, since this sounds exactly like an old problem I had.  If the fuses are good, try pulling relays and see what happens.  Make sure you post back when you get it fixed!  I'm interested

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed this.

The issue was with the BCM (Body Control Module) and SJB (Smart Junction Box)
There are no issues with fuses or relays, but rather the computer essentially cut power off to one wire for front lights (Front Light Control Module) due to a possible short circuit.

Because my light flickered a few times after installing HID, it eventually determined there was a possible short.

I was able to fix this on my own without a service visit by using a "Veepak" ODBII reader, and "FORscan" app from the Android Play store (7.99 is well worth it!)

The app was amazing, and allowed me to do a lot more than Torque could do (another app from Android PLaystore)

Using this app, I reset the FLCM (Front Light Control Module), and the BCM (Body Control Module).
Once reset, I ran "tests" which FORscan does, similar to the Ford Service software at dealerships, and performs a number of lighting and software tests - it revealed no issues and turned the headlight back on. The test was great, it goes through all warning scenarios on the phone, and causes the cluster to display that warning or similar (CIL,MILetc..) eventually comes back with fault found and explains it in details, or "OK"

In the end, it all made sense.
Because my HIDs that I installed were 55W, they didn't have enough power when the car was turning and caused the balast/light to flicker if the light was on while car was trying to start. 
When that happens enough, the car assumes a "Power to Ground short" (as the car's BCM displayed) and ceases to send power to that wire, until fixed.

The one thing I hate about this is that it does not show me this on my cluster, no check engine light, no MIL, etc.. which is odd since the car has a "System Health Check" option in the dashboard.

Additionally, the FORscan app I use will show me TPMS reads as well! 
I found it incredibly annoying that my car will simply say "OK" or "LOW" when my tire pressure is low or good, but not the actual reading.
This app will show you outer pressure, TPMS readings, etc.. for each tire!
THat's just one of thousands of other readings it can give you, along with module resets, and customizations and live data/diagnostics

I instantly fell in love with the app and think its well worth OVER 7.99 in my opinion! It saved me lots more money at the dealership.